# Odd behaviour with MKOverlayRenderer

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mkoverlay

I'm working on a project that uses `MKMapView` and requires quite a few overlays, and ran into some odd behaviour while rendering the overlays onto the map.

The delegate method is quite standard:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
    guard let line = overlay as? MKPolyline else { return MKOverlayRenderer() }
    let renderer = MKPolylineRenderer(polyline: line)
    renderer.lineWidth = 5
    renderer.alpha = 1
    renderer.strokeColor = UIColor.redColor()
    return renderer
}
```

But, for some reason, when scrolling the map roughly around the longitudes 180°W to 140°W  most or all vertical `MKPolyline`s between those longitudes disappear. And they only disappear on certain zoom levels, and only in this area.

How it looks when positioned in a specific way:
[image]

How it looks after zooming out a tiny bit:
[image]

In total I'm rendering 107 `MKPolyline`s, all of which consist of only two points.

If anybody has experienced similar behaviour while working with overlays and found a solution, I'd very much appreciate some insight on this.